# application / pdf is not a supported mime type at liferay 6.0.6

Tags: java, jasper-reports, liferay, liferay-6

I developed a custom portlet for Liferay 6.

Clicking on a link should open the popup to open/save a pdf file generated using Jasper Reports.

I use `response.setContentType ("application/pdf"`), where response is `RenderResponse`.

But it returns the following error:

> ERROR java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: application / pdf is not a supported mime type
>   at com.liferay.portlet.MimeResponseImpl.setContentType (MimeResponseImpl.java: 159)........

I also tried to add the tag in the file `portlet.xml`

```
<supports>
    <mime-type> application/pdf </mime-type>
    <portlet-mode> view </portlet-mode>
</supports>
```

but I always get the same error.

Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you shoud use `public void serveResource(ResourceRequest req, ResourceResponse res)` method in jsr-286 and use `res.setContentType("application/pdf")` in this method;

Comment: &@Dragos Bobolea,thanks for reply,is there a link or docs for more understanding

Comment: hey djoStack,
Were you able to resolve this issue ?  I am facing exactly the same problem.
Can you please help me out here ?

Answer (score 0):

As per Portlet 2.0 (which is supported by Liferay-6) we have 2 new portlet phases: [`Resource`](http://portlet-container.java.net/docs/jsr286.html#Serving_Resources) and [`Event`](http://portlet-container.java.net/docs/jsr286.html#Events).

Resource serving phase is useful for doing ajax stuff in portlets and for downloading i.e. serving resources like images/documents/pdf/files etc.

So just like you create a `renderURL` (`<portlet:renderURL />` or `renderResponse.createRenderURL()`) to call the `render` or `doView` method of your portlet similarly you need to create a `resourceURL` (`<portlet:resourceURL />` or `renderResponse.createResourceURL()`) to call the `serveResource` method of your portlet.

And in your `serveResource` method you can write the code which you have written current in your render method (some modifications may be required) to download the pdf.

For a complete example you can download this [source-code](https://code.google.com/p/portletsinaction/downloads/detail?name=chapter%2012-14.zip&can=2&q=) for 12th Chapter of [Portlets in Action](http://www.manning.com/sarin/) book, and refer the project named: **ch12_BookCatalogResourceURL**.